# SQL: Selecting 1 ROW from a TABLE where 3 COLUMNS have repeating values

Tags: sql, join, unique, distinct, data-wrangling

Trying to select a single row from a table where 2 different columns have repeating values.  I'm trying to left join to a different table with unique values.  However this table causes duplicate values.

| COLUMN1 | Column2 | COLUMN 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NAME1 | ID Numb1 | DESCR1 |
| NAME1 | ID Numb1 | DESCR2 |
| NAME1 | ID Numb2 | DESCR1 |
| NAME1 | ID Numb3 | DESCR1 |
| NAME2 | ID Numb3 | DESCR3 |
| NAME2 | ID Numb3 | DESCR1 |
| NAME2 | ID Numb4 | DESCR1 |
| NAME4 | ID Numb4 | DESCR1 |

I don't care which values for DESCR or ID Numb I get.

All I need one single row for each name with the corresponding ID Numb and DESCR attached to it.

I'm trying to join this to another table which already has unique values for NAME.

Help?

Comment: If you don't care what col2 and co3 are, why seelct them? If you want some kind of representative value just use MAX() to pick one out and group by column1

Comment: Please provide a table for expected output